# Как пользоваться less в css?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, less

То есть допустим я написал код на less. Теперь чтобы сайт работал не только локально, но и на сервере, мне нужно его откомпилировать в css. Правильно? Less нужен только для самого программиста во время написания, а пользователь получает стили с обычного css, я правильно понимаю? Или можно добавить less.js файл в проект он сам будет компилироваться у пользователя за счет ресурсов его ноутбука например?

Comment: CSS на странице (как и JS), в любом случае выполняются за счет ресурсов пользователя...

Comment: можно и так и так

Answer (score -1):

Поставьте нормальный вотчер и что локально, что на сайте сделайте ваши странички смотрящими на css. Вы ведь все равно будете заливать на сервер измененные файлы - вот и заливайте и .less, и .css сразу. .less юзер в принципе не увидит, если не догадается подставить явно расширение в урл.